# Referencing a specific row on a worksheet using a users input on a cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have data entries stored in separate rows on another worksheet, and wish to display specific data from a particular row by taking the users input of which row number to use in cell `M8`. (For example `M8` contains the number 2 as they wish to take data from row 2).

As an example on 1 cell, I'm using: `='IMPORT - CURRENT JOB'!EJ2` which returns the data I wish from Row 2.

I wish to replace the row 2 reference with a reference to the row noted in Cell `M8` by the user. Is this possible some how? I've used search and tried indirect, but think I'm formatting it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

This is the correct way to use [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en):

`=INDIRECT("'IMPORT - CURRENT JOB'!EJ"&M8)`

**Example:**

[image]